# Excel : Fill the fourth column based on the value on other three columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a solution to this problem

On the same sheet, I have three columns with rows of Yes and No.I need my fourth column to have an Yes if only all the three preceding columns have Yes, else No.

I wrote this formula, D1 =If(A1=Yes and B1=Yes and C1=Yes, "Yes", "No") but the value returns a #NAME? error. Can you please help ?

[@Mrig, I used the formula but don't know why isn't working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RI0Z.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula should be

```
=IF(AND(A1="Yes",B1="Yes",C1="Yes"), "Yes", "No")
```

For details on `AND` function see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9).

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Hi, when I used the formula, some records are returning correct values but some aren't.

Comment: @user61727 - Can you share the values for which the result is incorrect.

Comment: All three Nos are getting a Yes, all three Yes, Yes; even in one yes in a column, then an Yes.

Comment: @user61727 - See image in the answer.

Comment: Ive editied my question with the screenshot. Still no luck :(

Comment: @user61727 - What is your formula in `Cell D3`?

Comment: @user61727 - Or else try `=IF(AND(TRIM(A2)="Yes",TRIM(B2)="Yes",TRIM(C2)="Yes"), "Yes", "No")` if there are spaces around text.